# WPF designing: See entire scrollview

Tags: c#, wpf

I am designing a WPF program with a scrollviewer on a page.
My issue is that I can't see what I am doing the further down I go. Picture: 
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzdUH.png)

As you can see, there is a button outside of my actual view. I have tried to scroll down in visual studio, but I can't make it work.
If anyone knows the solution to this or have any tips, It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try increasing or setting a design height on root element of your Xaml (e.g. Window, UserControl, etc).

For example:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="1000" <----------THIS ONE
             d:DesignWidth="300">
    ...
</UserControl>
```